# Blue Squiggly Lines in app.config

Tags: xml, visual-studio, warnings, app-config

For the app.config file of a command line project in Visual Studio 2015 I get 99 warnings telling me an element was "already declared" and corresponding blue squiggly lines in the XML text editor for that file. I used the file properties to reference every XML Schema there is. That didn't help. The squiggly lines are at odd positions in the editor (for example at whitespace) and are only one character long. I find this to be unnerving and would like to get rid of it. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks alot!

PS: Other posts related to this topic were about problems with the enterprise library. Or including the right schema under properties/schemas solved it (which is noct the case for me)

Comment: Cannot say anything without seeing the file :(

Answer (score 2):

A few hours of investigating that phenomenon didn't bring up a solution. But shortly after posting my qustion, I found out how to answer it. I just had to delete all entries in properties/schema. Visual Studio then filled it with what seems to be the standard for that property. And voila, squiggly lines were gone. Also I got IntelliSense back for my app.config.

I assume, the reason for the odd behavior was me switching the .NET Framework of my console application project. Doing that, the selection of schema files for app.config somehow changed, too (I didn't recognice in what way). The result were missing or duplicated definitions in the sum of the XSDs.